# MYSQL delete where value = multiple POST values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to put this,

```
check_box=147&check_box=148&check_box=146 etc..
```

into

```
$delete_selected = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['check_box'])

$sql = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE cat_id = '$delete_selected'";
```

but it only deletes the first check_box value. Is there a way to loop through all the values?

Comment: That's because your "check_box" variable only has the first selected check_box for value. I don't know PHP much, but if that is indeed PHP, then the answer lies there.

Comment: Suggest converting all your incoming check_box values to an `IN()`. Any answer coming with that solution would get my vote.

Comment: Do you have influence on the name of the POST fields? I.e. can you make them e.g. `check_box[]`instead of `checkbox`? php will parse the former into an array while in the latter form only the last value is stored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your post vars to have `[]`, i.e. `checkbox[]=`. Once that's fixed, on to the backend...

Considering you neeed to escape every value, do something like this:

```
$clean_values = array();
foreach($_POST['check_box'] as $value){
    $clean_values[] = $connection->real_escape_string($value);
}

$sql = 'DELETE FROM categories WHERE cat_id in ('.implode(',',$clean_values).')';
```

**BONUS PHP5.3 ANSWER:**

```
array_walk($_POST['check_box'],function(&item) use($connection){
    $item = $connection->real_escape_string($item);
});
$sql = 'DELETE FROM categories WHERE cat_id in ('.implode(',',$_POST['check_box']).')';
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE cat_id in '($delete_selected)'";
```

I may have screwed up the php.  the resulting query should liik like

```
DELETE FROM categories WHERE cat_id in ('cat1', 'cat2', ...)
```

Comment: +1: You're right, but the OP also needs to check the PHP to get those values to populate the IN clause.

Answer (score 1):

Self-contained example to play with...

```
<html>
  <head><title>...</title></head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="?">
      <p>
        <!-- php will parse post fields like check_box[]=xyz as an array, appending new elements to $_POST['check_box'] -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_box[]" id="c1" value="140" /><label for="c1">140</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_box[]" id="c2" value="141" /><label for="c2">141</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_box[]" id="c3" value="142" /><label for="c3">142</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_box[]" id="c4" value="143" /><label for="c4">143</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_box[]" id="c5" value="144" /><label for="c5">144</label><br />
        <input type="submit" />
      </p>
    </form>
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['check_box']) && is_array($_POST['check_box']) ) {
  echo '<pre> _POST='; var_dump($_POST); echo '<pre>';

  // approach #1: treat ids as numbers. Keep the value range of php's integers and MySQL numeric fields in mind
  // make sure the elements really are integers
  $params = array_map('intval', $_POST['check_box']);
  // join the elements to one string like "1,2,3"
  $params = join(', ', $params);
  // use the IN operator in your WHERE-clause
  $sql = "DELETE FROM xyz WHERE cat_id IN ($params)";
  echo 'sql1 = ', $sql, "<br />";
  // mysql_query($sql, $mysql) or die(mysql_error());

  // approach #2: treat ids as strings.
  // you need a database connection for mysql_real_escape_string()
  $mysql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly') or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('test', $mysql) or die(mysql_error());

  // each element has to be escaped and put into single quotes
  $params = array_map(
    function($e) use ($mysql) {
      return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($e, $mysql)."'";
    },
    $_POST['check_box']
  );
  // again join them, "'1','2','x'"
  $params = join(', ', $params);
  // IN operator in WHERE-clause
  $sql = "DELETE FROM xyz WHERE cat_id IN ($params)";
  echo 'sql2 = ', $sql, "<br />";
  // mysql_query($sql, $mysql) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
  </body>
</html>
```